# Custom hostname for AWS ClientVPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, vpn, openvpn, wildcard-subdomain

Say I have the following record:

`*.foo.bar CNAME *.baz.qux`

If I do a DNS query on `test.foo.bar`, will it return the record for `test.baz.qux`? Or will it do something else?

**EDIT:** There's a reason for wanting to do this. AWS's Client VPN provides an endpoint with random prefix, e.g. `*.cvpn-endpoint-foo.bar.clientvpn.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`, meaning it will accept a connection with any value used for the prefix (used so there's no DNS caching of the endpoint's A records, corresponding to OpenVPN's `remote-random-hostname` option). I would like to provide a connection endpoint like `*.vpn.mydomain.com`. So, I was wondering if there was a way to do this, where a random prefix can be used with the custom domain and have it pass that through to the domain it CNAMEs to.

To summarize: is there a way I can use AWS's Client VPN random prefix via a custom DNS record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such `CNAME` record is illegal. You cannot have wildcard `*` as `CNAME` value, only single domain name at the RHS of `CNAME`. You can have something like

```
*.foo.bar. CNAME zuka.baz.qux.
```

Also, note the dots at the end of domain names. Without them zone name will be appended.

**Update** To clarify this. '*' in the RHS is *not* wild card, it is
treated as regular domain name. So, unless you have host or subdomain named `*.baz.qux` any query for `whatewer.foo.bar` will return `not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: AWS would seem to disagree with you. They have no problem accepting a CNAME record pointing to a wildcard. Can you direct me to an RFC that states it's illegal?

Comment: RFC 1034, section 3.6 and 3.6.2, RFC 1035,  section 3.3.1.

Comment: You update clarifies it, thanks. Would you mind taking a look at the edit on the original post, which provides more details?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this question after suffering the same confusion about wildcards and CNAMES. I managed to get a good solution thanks to Yuri's answer putting me in the right direction.

Basically I just chose my own 'random' fixed subdomain for the VPN Endpoint and pointed my `CNAME` entry to it. So if the VPN Endpoint DNS Name is:

```
*.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.<region>.amazonaws.com
```

Then I use the following CNAME entry:

```
vpn.my-domain.com CNAME <random>.cvpn-endpoint-xxxxxx.prod.clientvpn.<region>.amazonaws.com.
```

The above entry handles clients without `remote-random-hostname` capability. I can then add another wildcard `CNAME` to catch clients with this option enabled:

```
*.vpn.my-domain.com CNAME vpn.my-domain.com
```

With these two entries I can happily distribute vpn config that points to `vpn.my-domain.com` and re-map this in Route53 if I ever need to replace the VPN Endpoint.

Slightly related documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/troubleshooting.html#resolve-host-name